# Problem with web screenshots requiring authentication

Tags: screenshot

I am making app that takes a screenshot of a URL requested by the user. I want to make it as transparent as possible when sites that require username and passwords are in question.

For instance, if user wants to screenshot its iGoogle page, he will send the server URL but, the screenshot will not be the same as what he sees on his screen.

Is there any way to do this ? I guess that in such cases I will have to actually request screenshot from the user. Perhaps user can even deliver me his cookie for that domain.

Any thoughts ?

Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in most cases you'll need user's cookies.

*If* site uses regular cookies, you can create bookmarklet that reads `document.cookie`. This will not work with `httpOnly` cookies which are used increasingly often for sessions.

Some sites limit sessions to certain IP, and in that case you can't take screenshot without proxying request through user's computer.

If you can get user to use bookmarlet, an interesting trick would be to read and send DOM to your server:

```
image.src = 'http://example.com?source=' +
            escape(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

For HTTP authentication easiest solution would be to ask user for login/password.

Comment: Interesting. So, what of above you suggest as a most generall solution. The user can literally request anything to be screenshoted. The "interesting trick" is really interesting :) The problem is how to recognise such URLs that have a related cookie. If I can't recognise that, i can offer a user a choice, but not otherwise. So, in other words, there is no thing like "if site uses this or that". Site is random :)

Comment: More about interesting trick... Are you totally sure it will produce exact thing on the servers browser ? I kinda like the trick a lot :) Its really great thinking man.

Comment: It is _supposed_ to be exact, but of course reality, especially in IE, is different. IE might not show `<param>` elements or contents of inline `<script>` nodes.